# Android ndk-build not generating gdb.setup file

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am currently trying to debug native code in Android via ndk-gdb but I am having some troubles. 
Even if I start a very simple project (let's say for example a default cocos2d-x v3 project) and run

```
ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1
```

I end up with the following folder structure inside my android project

```
...
libs/
    armeabi/
        libcocos2dcpp.so
...
```

instead of the expected:

```
...
libs/
    armeabi/
        gdb.setup
        gdbserver
        libcocos2dcpp.so
...
```

In order to use ndk-gdb I need those two gdb files.

I am using cocos version 3.2 and Android NDK version r9d.

Isn't `NDK_DEBUG=1`enough for the gdb files to be generated? I have also tried with`android:debuggable="true"` inside my manifest file but it didn't work.

**Edit**

After running the command suggested by Digit I found a very suspicious line

```
Android NDK: Application 'local' forced *not* debuggable through NDK_DEBUG
```

when running the command `ndk-build NDK_LOG=1 NDK_DEBUG=1`

BUT

if I change to `ndk-build NDK_LOG=1 NDK_DEBUG=true` I get

```
Android NDK: Application 'local' forced debuggable through NDK_DEBUG
```

So it is ok now, really weird though how `=1` is not considered true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you paste the output of 'ndk-build NDK_LOG=1 NDK_DEBUG=1', this should contain more information about what ndk-build is doing, and is likely to provide an explanation.